# Wamp sub domain to run on http

Tags: php, windows, iis, wamp

I have a windows IIS server 2016 version 10 and i have a production server running in a virtualenv with wampp server running in https (ssl enabled)

I have a folder `mainFolder` in which my website is running https://mywebsite.com and i have a sub folder `Mobile` inside main MainFolder

I want to run a sub-domain using `Mobile` Folder http://mobile.website.com

After adding subdomain in go daddy my sub-domain is active and i made changes in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mobile.localhost.com
    ServerAlias mobile.localhost.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/website/Mobile
    
    <directory "c:/wamp64/www/webiste/Mobile/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after seeing this tutorial https://web.archive.org/web/20180323082634/http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/03/how-to-setup-local-subdomains-using-wampserver/

Now my subdomain is able to run in https but it access the main directory and i want to run my sub domain in http .
when i open my sub domian in http it says file not found (404 status code)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 404.